# How to search type Cp1252 but get all result type UTF-8 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a key word `song`

I have constants `ò,ó,ọ`

In the database I have entries: `song`, `sòng`, `sóng`, `sọng`,`abc`, `xyz`...

I want write a script (SQL Server stored procedure) to retrieve values like song: `song`, `sóng`, `sòng`, `sọng`.

Comment: And you still have not answered my other question. Don't make us jump through hoops to help you - provide all information that is asked for clarification. We are also missing your field structure. Questions here are supposed to show some effort/attempt, this is not *Can you write my code for me* site.

Comment: Infact, i have tried. But it is not good.

example: i removed the charapter 'o' by '_'
SELECT col FROM [dbo].[table] where col like '%s_ng%';

Comment: Also, explain better how the title ties in the actual question. There's no mention of Cp1252 or UTF-8 in the actual question text. Be as precise as possible.

Comment: yep. thank you.But in this case. Key word is cp1252(a type popular) and database is UTF-8 (have some characters is special).

Comment: If you want song, sòng, sóng, sọng all to compare equal you need to use an accent insensitive collation.